# How to send response to client and terminate whole function immediately and not return to the next callback

Tags: node.js, express, callback

```
    router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let user;
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }).then(_user => {
        if (!_user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
            });
        }
        user = _user;
        return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, _user.passwordHash);
    }).then(valid => {
        if (!valid) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
            });
        }
        try {
            const token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, id: user._id },
            "somesecret", { expiresIn: '1h' }
            );
        }
        catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            token: token
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Internal Server Error'
        });
    })
});
```

From the first "User.findOne" callback, I want to send response back to client and terminate the function immediately, but it will only return out of the first anonymous callback function, and proceed to the second callback anonymous function that checks for variable "valid" and unexpected things will happen like writing the response the second time and causes more error. Is there any better way to implement all these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you use express js, you need to use res/end in order to end the response. After that return.
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end

After talking to you in the comment, I still don't get why you chain promises, but if you want to do this your way, one way to skip the "then" is to throw an error, that will take you to the "catch" section.
try this and tell me if this is the behavior that you want.

instead of:

```
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
        });
```

try:

```
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
        });
        res.end();
       throw new Error("Username or password is incorrect")
```

this will jump right to the end.

If this is not the way you want it to work, you need to explain - what is the return for? what do you want to return and when?
Is there a difference between your return and your express responses?
the flow is not clear enough to me.

If you want cleaner code while still using promises, you can use async await. Read about it here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Yes. I am using express. The problem is the code will still continue to run/execute even I put return, which cause unexpected result like execute "res.status(401)" twice and causes more errors., because the return will only return out of the anonymous callback function not the whole router.post function...

Comment: I need some clarification. Why do you need another then?
If you are returning somthing, it should be the end of the function, and I see that you return something what ever you do in the first then.
The correct way to do this is to store all the things you want to return to the user in one place (such as an object or array) and return it all at the end.
If you want to send multiple messages back, you can use server sent events:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: another then is for proceeding the bcrypt callback/promise function. It is a promise chaining?

Comment: if I don't return the bcrypt callback, how do I proceed to run bcrypt? because it has a callback function too

Comment: @Inhumane I edited my answer, tell me if that is the behavior you wanted.

Comment: throwing exception works too, but I think the main problem with my code is there are asynchronous functions that require a lot of callback and I am trying to avoid callback hell, not sure what is the better chain this, so I return the asynchronous function and chain it using the next then, so usually what is a good way to chain asynchronous function?

Comment: @Inhumane the cleanest way to handle multiple promises chained together is using async await. you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks! that's is way much cleaner code, but what about if any of the async code throws rejection/error? How does the express js handle them? do I really need to put try catch block in every await statement just to catch the reject/error?

Comment: @Inhumane wrap in try catch clause, just like any other js code

Comment: @Inhumane unfortunately, I don't know on any other way other than try catch for every async await statement. But it won't be different in any other way - regardless of the method you use you will need to handle errors seperatly.